# Subtract one correct point for every 3 wrong point in kotlin

Tags: function, kotlin, while-loop

I want to subtract one correct point for every 3 wrong point and then print the current point (in a textView). For example we have 6 wrong point and 3 correct point, so we subtract one correct point for every 3 wrong point, and the answer is 1 correct point. Now I want code this in kotlin but I don't know how can I do it exactly.

This is my kotlin code:

```
fun calculateNetResult() {
        while (wrongIndex % 3 == 0) {
            correctIndex--
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please elaborate on your question. It is not clear what you are trying to do and what is wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using

```
import kotlin.math.max

fun calculateNetResult(): Int = max(0, correctIndex - wrongIndex / 3)
```

Assuming you don't need negative score points.

If your method contains only a single statement you can write it with equal sign as shown in kotlin just a shorthand syntax while the max will prevent the net score from going below zero.

Comment: sorry added min instead of max try to copy the code again and use

Comment: Please accept if this solves your problem